# Spring REST API with Multipart File Upload not working for optional parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, file-upload, multipart

I'm using Spring framework, but not too familiar with it. I'm writing a REST API, specifically a POST method that handles a file upload where the file is optional.

I've tried to simplify the method down but still having a problem. Here is what I have

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/items")
public String create(@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file) {
    return "Create";
}
```

The method works fine when I include a file in my form request, however when I don't have a file (as I want it to be optional). I have tried replacing the `@RequestParam` with a `HttpServletRequest` parameter yielding the same results.

I get a 500 error with the following stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.&lt;init&gt;(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:906)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2806)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3096)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1145)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:382)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:311)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2737)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3096)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1145)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:382)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:480)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:889)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.&lt;init&gt;(FileUploadBase.java:854)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:259)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:283)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2737)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3096)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1145)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:382)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

I found only one post in my search on the web and it talks about this potentially being a bug in Spring.  I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and would great appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: Is this error coming only in Internet Explorer or all the browsers? Try adding a hidden input field in the form. Make sure this hidden form field has a dummy value and is at the end of your form.

Comment: Do you have enctype attribute in your form post? What is the value of it?

Comment: I was using a Chrome app to test the call. I tried including the different enctype attributes to no luck.

I actually figured out how to do it. I don't know if it's optimal though. What I did was, I made the signature of the method to not include anything that uses Multipart but instead included a parameter for HttpServletRequest, then in the body I casted the object to a MultipartHttpServletRequest type. I'm now able to handle both types.

Thanks for your comments

Comment: @GeekyDevs could you provide your solution in the answer part?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I ended up with.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/object")
ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestParam("is_file") boolean isFile, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(isFile) {
      MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
      MultipartFile file = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
    } else{
      // You can add other parameters (as long as it isn't a multipart parameter) and do other stuff here
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I can see question is a bit old, but I put my answer here because uploading files topic is always alive.
I tested Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE in context of this question.
I defined rest service as below and it works when file is not attached to multipart/form-data.
I tested service with RestTemplate client.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestPart(value = "name", required = false) String name,
                                     @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just adding the `required=false` worked for me. Please find the sample code below,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/items")
public String create(@RequestParam(value ="file", required=false) MultipartFile file) {
    return "Create";
}
```